# Regarding models associations for belongsto

Tags: cakephp

Previously I used cakephp version 1.3.1  and model associations worked fine, but in version 2.3.2 associations aren't working.

I created one controller with name of Listings:

```
class ListingsController extends AppController {
    var $uses = 'Listing';
    var $name = 'Listings';
    var $components = array();

    function getFeatured(){
        $listing = $this->Listing->read();
        $this->Listing->recursive = 1;
        $today = date('Y-m-d');
        $listings = $this->Listing->find('all', array('conditions'=>'Listing.featured_expiration >='.$today,'order'=>'Rand()'));
        return $listings;
    }

//**** Function For Retreve All Properties Counts **** //
}
```

In models I created

```
class Listing extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Listing';
    var $displayField = 'full_address';
    var $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),      
    );    
}
```

But I am not getting the Users table records.

It works fine locally. I tried using containable behaviour too but had the same problem.

Thanks

Comment: will pls add your user class and file name here ?

Comment: does your listings table definitely have that field (user_id), and are there definitely records in it that have corresponding records in your users table?

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but some remarks to improve your code. I post this as an answer,  because a comment allows limited space;

### do not use `var` for properties

Var was used in older versions of CakePHP for compatibility with PHP 4. For PHP5, use `public`, `protected` or `private` to explicitly set their [visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).

All the properties in the code you posted should be `public`, so can be changed to;

```
 public $name = 'Listing';
 public $displayField = 'full_address';
 //etc
```

### Remove unnecessary options in your relations

In your example, the empty options only add 'clutter' (and sometimes may even cause unwanted side-effects). Remove the `fields`, `conditions` and `order` options.

Even further, because aparently your Models follow the CakePHP conventions, you don't have to set any option at all; both these will work fine:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(),
);
```

Or even:

```
public $belongsTo = array('User');
```

### Remove unused queries

Why are you performing *two* queries inside `getFeatured()`? The result of the first query (`$listing = $this->Listing->read();`) is not even used and can be removed

### Data related code should be performed in your models.

The method `getFeatured()` really doesn't belong in the Controller. Even worse, because it's a *public* method, it can be accessed via the browser! (via `http://yourdomain.com/listings/getFeatured/`) it will probably show an error if not view-file is found, but the queries inside the method **will be executed**

Move the method to the Listing model. You will have to make some minor modifications;

```
class Listing extends AppModel {
    // rest of the code here 

    public function getFeatured(){
        //Moved this to within the 'find' parameters
        //to only change recursive for *this* find
        //and not influence other queries after running
        //this one
        //$this->recursive = 1;

        return $this->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                // NOTE: use an associative array here
                'Listing.featured_expiration >=' => date('Y-m-d'),
            ),
            'recursive' => 1,

            // NOTE: check if this really works
            //      Cake *may* treat this as a literal
            //      value (string "Rand()")
            'order' => 'Rand()'
        ));
    }
}
```

Now, if you want to use this inside your controller, use this:

```
$this->Listing->getFeatured();
```